# Wordpress DB Query not updating table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been stuck on this for a while now. I have one table updating correctly ($table), but can't seem to get the second "$tabled" table to update. I know it must be something silly. Any insight on this is greatly appreciated!

Below is my full code:

```
<?php add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

function admin_register_head() {
$siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
$url = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/style.css';
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$url' />\n";
}add_action('admin_head', 'admin_register_head');

function my_plugin_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'Elo Calculator', 'Elo Calculator', 'manage_options', 'elo', 'my_plugin_options');}

function my_plugin_options() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}

global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix.elo;
$tabled = $wpdb->prefix.elomatches;

// check if elo db exists, otherwise create it
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'") != $table)
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        fn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        ln VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        elo INT(4) DEFAULT '1500' NOT NULL,
        experience INT(11) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
// check if elomatches db exists, otherwise create it
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$tabled'") != $tabled)
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tabled (
        winnerid int(11) NOT NULL,
        loserid int(11) NOT NULL,
        date int(11) NOT NULL,
        matchlength int(11) NOT NULL
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}

// delete users

if (isset($_GET['delete']) && is_numeric($_GET['delete']))
{
    $id = $_GET['delete']; 
    // delete from elo
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id='$id'");
    // delete from elomatch
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $tabled WHERE winnerid='$id' || loserid = '$id'");
}

// undo last match

if (isset($_GET['undo']) && is_numeric($_GET['undo']))
{
    // get last match info
    $matchid = $_GET['undo'];
    $last = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $tabled WHERE matchid='$matchid';");
    $match = $last->matchlength;

    $winnerid = $last->winnerid;
    $winnerelo = $last->winnerelo;
    $exp = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$winnerid';");
    $winnerexp = $exp->experience - $match;

    $loserid = $last->loserid;
    $loserelo = $last->loserelo;
    $exp = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$loserid';");
    $loserexp = $exp->experience - $match;

    // input old elo and experience to the winner
    $wpdb->update($table, array('elo' => $winnerelo, 'experience' => $winnerexp), array('id' =>$winnerid));
    // input old elo to the loser
    $wpdb->update($table, array('elo' => $loserelo, 'experience' => $loserexp), array('id' =>$loserid));

    // delete match
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $tabled WHERE matchid='$matchid'");

    ?><p class="success">&#10004; Undo successful</p><?php
}

// submit forms

if (isset($_POST['add_submit']))
{ // insert new player with default Elo of 1500
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['fn']) && $_POST['fn'] != 'First name')
    {
        $fn = $wpdb->escape($_POST['fn']);
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a First name';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ln']) && $_POST['ln'] != 'Last name')
    {
        $ln = $wpdb->escape($_POST['ln']);
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a Last name';
    }

    if (empty($errors))
    { // enter new player
        $elo = '1500';

        $wpdb->insert(
            $table,
            array(
                'fn' => $fn,
                'ln' => $ln,
                'elo' => $elo
            )
        );
        ?><p class="success">&#10004; New player added</p><?php
        unset($fn);
        unset($ln);
    }
    else
    {
        ?><h2 class="delete">Errors</h2>
        <ul><?php
            foreach ($errors as $error)
            {
                ?><li><?=$error;?></li><?php
            }
        ?></ul><?php
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ // calculate Elo
    $errors = array();
    // IDs
    if (isset($_POST['playerone']) && is_numeric($_POST['playerone']))
    {
        $p1id = $wpdb->escape($_POST['playerone']);
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please select Player one';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['playertwo']) && is_numeric($_POST['playertwo']))
    {
        $p2id = $wpdb->escape($_POST['playertwo']);
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please select Player two';
    }

    // are they same?

    if ($p1id == $p2id)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Players cannot be the same.';
    }

    // winner
    if (isset($_POST['results']) && is_numeric($_POST['results']))
    {
        $winner = $wpdb->escape($_POST['results']);
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please select a winner';
    }
    // match length
    if (isset($_POST['matchlength']) && is_numeric($_POST['matchlength']))
    {
        $n = $wpdb->escape($_POST['matchlength']);
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Please select a match length';
    }

    if (empty($errors))
    { // do all calculations

        function getElo($exp, $n, $winnerelo, $loserelo, $f)
        {
            if ($exp < 400)
            { // use the ramp or not?
                $pe = 5-(($exp+$n)/100);
            }
            else
            {
                $pe = 1;
            }
            $d = $winnerelo - $loserelo;
            $u = 1/((pow(10, $d*sqrt($n)/2000))+1);
            if ($f == 1)
            {
                $u = (1-$u);
            };
            // return new Elo
            return number_format(4*$pe*sqrt($n)*$u);
        }

        $p1 = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = $p1id");
        $p2 = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = $p2id");

        $p1elo = $p1->elo;
        $p2elo = $p2->elo;

        $p1exp = $p1->experience;
        $p2exp = $p2->experience;

        // f or u
        if ($p1elo >= $p2elo && $winner == 1)
        {
            $f = NULL;
        }
        if ($p1elo >= $p2elo && $winner == 2)
        {
            $f = 1;
        }
        if ($p1elo < $p2elo && $winner == 1)
        {
            $f = 1;
        }
        if ($p1elo < $p2elo && $winner == 2)
        {
            $f = NULL;
        }

        // player one
        if ($winner == 1)
        {
            $win = $p1id;
            $p1 = $p1elo + getElo($p1exp, $n, $p1elo, $p2elo, $f);
            // elo for undo
            $winelo = $p1elo;
        }
        else
        {
            $lose = $p1id;
            $p1 = $p1elo - getElo($p1exp, $n, $p1elo, $p2elo, $f);
            // elo for undo
            $losselo = $p1elo;
        }
        $wpdb->update($table, array('elo' => $p1, 'experience' => $p1exp+$n), array('id' =>$p1id));

        // player two
        if ($winner == 2)
        {
            $win = $p2id;
            $p2 = $p2elo + getElo($p2exp, $n, $p1elo, $p2elo, $f);
            // elo for undo
            $winelo = $p2elo;
        }
        else
        {
            $lose = $p2id;
            $p2 = $p2elo - getElo($p2exp, $n, $p1elo, $p2elo, $f);
            // elo for undo
            $losselo = $p2elo;
        }

        $wpdb->update($table, array('elo' => $p2, 'experience' => $p2exp+$n), array('id' =>$p2id));

        // update win/loss database
        $date = time();
        $wpdb->update($tabled, array('winnerid' => $win, 'loserid' => $lose, 'date' => $date, 'matchlength' => $n, 'winnerelo' => $winelo, 'loserelo' => $losselo));

        ?>
        <p class="success">&#10004; Elo updated</p><?php
        unset($win);
        unset($lose);
        unset($winner);
        unset($n);
        unset($p1id);
        unset($p2id);
    }
    else
    {
        ?><h2 class="delete">Errors</h2>
        <ul><?php
            foreach ($errors as $error)
            {
                ?><li><?=$error;?></li><?php
            }
        ?></ul><?php
    }
}
// last match date
$lastmatch = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MAX(date) AS updated FROM $tabled ORDER BY date DESC;");
// get last match
$lastwin = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $tabled INNER JOIN $table ON $tabled.winnerid=$table.id ORDER BY $tabled.date DESC LIMIT 1;");
$lastloss = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $tabled INNER JOIN $table ON $tabled.loserid=$table.id ORDER BY $tabled.date DESC LIMIT 1;");
// get user list
$users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ln ASC;");
$elo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY elo DESC, ln ASC;");
?><div class="wrap">
    <style>
        ul.half li {width: 50%; float: left; font-family: georgia;}
        .wrap p {font-family: georgia; font-size: 1.2em;}
        .length {font-size: 1.2em; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 5px;}
        .select {font-size: 1.2em;}
        table {font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 1.4em;}
        input[type=submit] {font-size: 1.4em; padding: 5px;}
        .delete {color: red; font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;}
        .success:first-letter {color: green; font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;}
        .small-caps {font-variant: small-caps;}
    </style>
    <h2><a href="admin.php?page=elo">Elo Calculator</a></h2>
    <p><strong>Last match:</strong> <?=$lastwin->fn;?> <?=$lastwin->ln;?> <span class="small-caps">vs</span> <?=$lastloss->fn;?> <?=$lastloss->ln;?> on <?=date('F j, Y @ h:ia', $lastmatch->updated-25200);?></p>
    <form name="new_elo" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
    <p>
        <label for="new_player">Add player:</label>
        <input type="text" value="First name" name="fn" onfocus="if (this.value == 'First name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First name';}" />
        <input type="text" value="Last name" name="ln" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Last name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last name';}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="add_submit" />
    </p>
    <hr />
    <form name="add_elo" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
        <ul class="half">
            <li>
                <h3>Player one</h3>
                <select name="playerone" class="select">
                    <option></option>
                    <?php 
                    foreach ($users as $row)
                    {
                        if (isset($p1id) && $p1id == $row->id)
                        {
                            $selected = ' SELECTED';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $selected = NULL;
                        }
                        ?><option value="<?=$row->id;?>"<?=$selected;?>><?=$row->fn;?> <?=$row->ln;?> (<?=$row->elo;?>)</option><?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <?php
                if (isset($winner) && $winner == 1)
                {
                    $checked = ' checked';
                }
                else
                {
                    $checked = NULL;
                }
                ?>
                <p><input type="radio" name="results" value="1" id="p1"<?=$checked;?> /> <label for="p1" class="length">Winner</label></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>Player two</h3>
                <select name="playertwo" class="select">
                    <option></option>
                    <?php 
                    foreach ($users as $row)
                    {
                        if (isset($p2id) && $p2id == $row->id)
                        {
                            $selected = ' SELECTED';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $selected = NULL;
                        }
                        ?><option value="<?=$row->id;?>"<?=$selected;?>><?=$row->fn;?> <?=$row->ln;?> (<?=$row->elo;?>)</option><?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <?php
                if (isset($winner) && $winner == 2)
                {
                    $checked = ' checked';
                }
                else
                {
                    $checked = NULL;
                }
                ?>
                <p><input type="radio" name="results" value="2" id="p2"<?=$checked;?> /> <label for="p2" class="length">Winner</label></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear: both" />
        <h3>Match length</h3>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="matchlength" checked="checked"  value="1" id="l1"<?php if (isset($n) && $n == 1) { echo ' CHECKED';}?>> <label for="l1" class="length">1</label>

        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <br />
    <table class="widefat">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Elo</th>
            <th>Record</th>
            <th>Win percentage</th>
            <th>Experience</th>
            <th>Delete player</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($elo as $row)
        {
            $wins = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tabled WHERE winnerid = $row->id;"));
            $losses = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tabled WHERE loserid = $row->id;"));
            ?><tr>
                <td><?=$row->fn;?> <?=$row->ln;?></td>
                <td><?=$row->elo;?></td>
                <td><?=$wins;?> - <?=$losses;?></td>
                <td><?php if ($wins > 0) {echo 100*number_format($wins/($wins+$losses), 2).'%';} else {echo '0%';}?></td>
                <td><?=$row->experience;?></td>
                <td><a class="delete" href="http://vancouverbg.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=elo&amp;delete=<?=$row->id;?>">&times;</a></td>
            </tr><?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a href="admin.php?page=elo&amp;undo=<?=$lastwin->matchid;?>">Undo last match</a></p>
</div><?php }
```

Comment: The only place where $tabled is getting updated is `$wpdb->update($tabled ... )` - is this the query that isn't working?

Comment: Yes that is the update query that is not working. There are a few places where it calls for data from that table for display, but obviously it shows nothing as the table is not ever being populated with data.

Comment: What does `echo $wpdb->last_error` say if you insert it right after the update?

Comment: Yeah I inserted that echo just after the $wpdb->update($tabled, array('winnerid' => $win, 'loserid' => $lose, 'date' => $date, 'matchlength' => $n, 'winnerelo' => $winelo, 'loserelo' => $losselo)); line and I did not get an error.